# Как вывести связь many-to-many django

Tags: django

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести содержимое связи many-to-many в шаблоне.
К примеру есть модель:

```
class Variety(models.Model):
    varietyName = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.varietyName

class Fruits(models.Model):
    fruitName = models.ManyToManyField(Specs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fruitName
```

Я создал в таблице "Fruits" запись "Яблоки", в таблице "Variety" создал виды яблок(красные,зелёные,гнилые и т.д) и соединил с "Яблоки" в таблице "Fruits".
Как теперь это всё правильно передать в шаблон и вывести?

к премеру во `view.py` есть ф-ция, которая срабатывается при заходе на главную страницу. Я так понял, что значения нужно передавать так?

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'fruits': Fruits.objects.all()})
```

Если так, то как их вывести виды яблок шаблоне?

Comment: у вас модели Variety и Fruits не связанны между собой

Comment: `return "self.fruitName"` так не пишут, это во первых не логично, во вторых неправильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если немного модернизировать вашу модель, до следующего вида:

```
class Variety(models.Model):
    varietyName = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.varietyName

class Fruits(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    variety = models.ManyToManyField(Variety)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

то можно выгружать связанные объекты. Заметьте, что я изменил метод `__str__`. Не логично возвращать строковое представление группы объектов.

Во views всё нормально, в шаблоне вы можете выводить значения циклом по фруктам и у каждого фрукта выгружать список его видов.
Пример:

```
{% for fruit in fruits %}
    <h5>{{ fruit.name }}</h5> // название фрукта
    {% for v in fruit.variety.all %}
        <h5>{{ v.varietyName }}</h5> // название вида
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

[Для более подробного описания можно обратиться к документации.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Да, спасибо. На счёт __str__ - это не преднамеренная ошибка, свой код скопировал и забыл строку поменять, а там именно строка + значение переменной возвращается.

Comment: Кстати, для оптимизации таких запросом можете посмотреть `prefetch_related`.